# how do i run vb macros outside example.xlsx excel file to clean format of excel file using code ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats?

Tags: excel, vba

how do i run vb macros outside example.xlsx excel file to clean format of excel file using code ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats ?
how can i run this command from .vb file?

Comment: Can you add a new one with application.workbooks.add

Comment: i mean how can i run ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats from vb script on file  example.xlsx

Comment: Your open workbooks are available in the object model and can be run from any other file. However, if you have both files open and then from "this workbook" if you go to "view" and then "macros" you can select and run a macro that is in another file. I have a list of common macros I run and I can run them on any file just by opening it when I need them.

Comment: can i process excel file from vb script file without opening it ?

Comment: I open two file and try to run macros from another file in my new file and it is not working?

Comment: Do you have an answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little digging "thisWorkbook" is only for the file that contains it. "ActiveWorkbook" is when it's run from another open file. 
If you have your macro file open and then access view menu and then macros from the other file you can use the dropdown to see the other macros and run it on the open file.
There is further discussion of this here: http://codevba.com/excel/set_workbook.htm